# counting occurrences in multiple columns and computing statistics with R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm a newbie in dplyr.
Here is my simplified data frame:

```
ID S1 S2 S3
1  45 36 101
1  10 45 101
1  81 81 45
2  45 101 81
2  36 36 45
```

First, I want to summarize the occurrence of each number in S1-S3 by ID:

```
ID 45 36 101 10 81
1  3  1   2   1  1
2  2  2   1   0  1
```

Then, I want to compute means, std, and CI for each column (except for ID).
I tried to do the first stage with dplyr:

```
df %>% summarize(by_SS, count=n())
```

But this just counted ID's:

```
1.0 3
2.0 2
```

How can this be done?

Comment: take a look at the use of `group_by`  and `summarise` together, and you might want to consider reshaping your data, in any case I have added an answer of one way you can do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dplyr generally is easier with "long format". You get the answer with:

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(gmodels)

 # First part
 df <- df %>% gather(k, v, S1:S3) %>% 
     add_count(ID, v) %>% 
     mutate(v = as.character(v),
            v = ifelse(is.na(v), "missing", v)) %>% 
     select(-k) %>% 
     distinct() %>% 

 # Second part. For each count of values summarize
 # mean, ci, and sd. ci produces all which we can utilize.
 # Lastly, make values rownames and transpose.
     group_by(v) %>% 
     summarize(mean      = ci(n)[1],
               lower_ci  = ci(n)[2],
               upper_ci  = ci(n)[3],
               sd        = ci(n)[4]*sqrt(length(n))) %>% 
   remove_rownames %>% 
   column_to_rownames(var="v") %>% 
   t()
```

Comment: How do I do step 2?

Comment: I don't understand all the code. Could you explain a bit what's happening here?

Comment: Absolutely. 1. Gather takes the columns S1:S3 and stacks them on top of each other keeping all other values constant. This creates a column with the variables S1:S3, and another column with their values. 2. add_count  counts how many occurences there are for every ID and value. 3. select(-k), the column k has the information of S1:S3, but since your final answer dont have S1 through S3 we can remove that column.  4. Distinct, Since we dont want to count the 45 for ID 1 more than oncewe remove dublicates. 5. Spread takes the numbers you want to count back to columns. Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: Very clear! So now I want to compute statistics for each column, but where is the new table/df saved!?

Comment: See edited answer. Don't worry about the warnings. It just warns you that you cant get sd from only one observation value (10 in your example). Good luck!

Comment: I get the following error warning, without any results:                                                    
    Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
    missing values in 'row.names' are not allowed
    In addition: Warning message:
    Setting row names on a tibble is deprecated.

Comment: Ah! Thats because you have missing values in your data, and a column cant be named NA. I added two lines (where it says mutate) to change NA to the word missing which can be used as a column name in the final result.

Comment: If you dont care about the missing values you can replace the two mutate rows of the code with drop.na(v) %>%

Comment: NA solved! But the SD's computed are incorrect...checked in SPSS

Comment: What significance level of the confidence interval do you want?

Comment: The CI is OK (alpha=0.05), the problem is with the computation of the SD. The results are not correct.

Answer (score 0):

here is one suggestion of how this can be done

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape)

# reading your example
df <- read.table(text = ('ID S1 S2 S3
1  45 36 101
1  10 45 101
1  81 81 45
2  45 101 81
2  36 36 45'), header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

# reshaping the data
df_1 <- df %>% melt(id.vars = 'ID')

# getting the results
table(df_1$ID, df_1$value)

#   10 36 45 81 101
# 1  1  1  3  2   2
# 2  0  2  2  1   1
```

Comment: Great! so this solves step 1. Any ideas how to do step 2 (compute mean,sd,ci)?